# Derived query through relationship is empty if the field is empty

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, orm

So I have a `Student` entity:

```java
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String studentID;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_detail_id")
    private StudentDetail studentDetailID; }
```

`StudentDetail` entity:

```java
public class StudentDetail {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Religion religionID;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "studentDetailID", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Student student; }
```

The flow of my API is that if you want to add `studentDetail` into a `Student` **later**, you can call `/detail/{studentID}`, that's why I create this query:

```java
public interface StudentDetailRepository extends JpaRepository<StudentDetail, Long> {
    Optional<StudentDetail> findByStudentStudentID(String studentID);}
```

And this is my `@Service`:

```java
    public StudentDetailDTO getStudentDetail(String studentID) {
        Optional<StudentDetail> studentOptional = studentDetailRepository.findByStudentStudentID(studentID);
        if (studentOptional.isEmpty()) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException(STUDENT_NOT_FOUND_STRING + studentID);
        }
        StudentDetail studentDetail = studentOptional.get();

        return studentDetailMapper.toDTO(studentDetail);
    }
```

The problem is, `studentOptional` will be empty and throw Exception if:

1. The `studentID` doesn't exist (expected)
2. The `Student` exists but `studentDetail` is null

The problem is the 2nd reason, because `studentDetail` is allowed to be null first. I suspect maybe because of lazy fetch, but it's required since there are a lot of fields.

Please help me with a solution or a different approach to this API flow.